# At what OSI layer do AWS Security Groups operate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I've read couple of articles about AWS Security Groups:

- [Amazon EC2 security groups for Linux instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)
- [Security Groups for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

but couldn't find at which OSI layer Security Groups operate. Maybe someone can help me understand at which OSI layer they operate?

Comment: I'm not sure where it fits in the OSI layers, but I like to think of a Security Group as being a firewall attached to individual EC2 instances (or, to be more accurate, to every Elastic Network Interface). Traditionally, firewalls operate _between subnets_, but a Security Group adds additional protection at the resource-level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security Groups make it possible to create traffic allow rules based on IPs, protocols and optionally ports. IPs are associated with Layer 3 (Network) of the OSI-model and Ports with Layer 4 (Transport). The protocols you can filter on are a little tougher - you can select some from layer 3 (e.g. ICMP), layer 4 (e.g. TCP/UDP) or layer 5+ (HTTP,...) in the console. If you select one of the layer 5+ protocols, it will actually set TCP or UDP for you.

As a result of that, I would say that the security group operates at both layer 3 and layer 4 of the OSI model. I'm not sure if that really fits in the model, but I'm not very dogmatic about the model - as the statisticians say: *All models are wrong, but some are useful.*

Comment: Security Groups are stateful, meaning that if inbound traffic is allowed outbound traffic is automatically allowed. May it be the case that SGs operate at Layer 5 - Session?

Comment: As statefulness is achieved using only layer 3 and 4 concepts (IP + Port), I don't think this belongs into Layer 5. My understanding is, that layer 5 is more about managing the session of the actual program using the underlying protocols, so something like cookies in the case of HTTP.